# Is datawarehouse considered as datalake in big data environnment?

Tags: bigdata

Suppose I have a datawarehouse (DWH) and now I would like to add many other bigdata sources of information most of them are not structured. I still keep the DWH with no architectural change. The only thing I do is to enrich the bigdata with the data resides in the DWH using connectivity. Can the DWH defined as datalake in this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out this article: http://www.kdnuggets.com/2015/09/data-lake-vs-data-warehouse-key-differences.html

Looks like the answer is yes, your DWH can be defined as datalake because you are adding unstructured data.  Here is an excerpt:

> “A data lake is a storage repository that holds a vast amount of raw data in its native format, including structured, semi-structured, and unstructured data. The data structure and requirements are not defined until the data is needed.”